# Streaming H.264 video from a Raspberry Pi on an iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming

Full disclosure: I'm a pretty junior developer and new to asking questions. I also don't know that much about video streaming as a concept so if the answer is right in front of my face I probably just glazed right over it.

That being said, I am trying to do something that seems like it should be pretty simple but can't seem to figure it out. I'm trying to get a H.264 live stream video off of a Raspberry Pi and view it in my app. I've found a number of things about encoding videos but couldn't seem to get anything to work.

Anything anyone has to offer would be a large help, even if it is just a direction to look in because I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure this one out.

Comment: Are you using any tool/protocol yet? If not, take a loot at Wowza or Red5

Comment: No I am not. Should I be if all I want to do is view the live stream from the Raspberry Pi in my iOS app? I apologize if this question is silly but I'm just trying to grok this and understand how I should be coming at this.

Comment: Please enlighten with more details. How do you want to conduct this stream? via internet, local network or some other medium? Is it the video file or live stream?

Comment: So at the moment it is on my local network, most likely it will always be so local network will be fine for now. It is a live stream thought, my bad I thought I specified that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll first need to install some platform on your Raspberry Pi that can serve data to a client. You can look into web server platforms like `Apache`. Once installed, you can verify this is working by hitting the IP address of the Raspberry Pi from any browser: e.g. `192.168.1.67:80`

Then you need to make sure the video is available through the file system on your Raspberry Pi. Searching something like "Adding files to Apache" might help.

You can test that the file is available by hitting the IP address of your Raspberry Pi from any browser: e.g.
`192.168.1.67:80/path/to/video.mp4`

This means that the video file is available and can be downloaded, but won't be streamed by default. Then you can look into some JavaScript framework that can help you with the streaming portion.

Comment: So I forgot to specify in my question but the Raspberry Pi is on my local network and I am attempting to play the video as it is streaming (live).

Comment: Sure, but first your RP needs a way of serving that video. Take it one step at a time. You need 3 things first:
1. Web Server (Install `Apache` on your RP if it isn't installed already)
2. IP address of your RP
3. Path to the video file to serve

Comment: You can't just go from "I have a Raspberry Pi" to "I am now streaming movies to my iPhone." There are various things you need to install and configure.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has super famous HLS protocol for streaming videos. You would need to first encode video input coming from camera, then pass it to your server who's basically doing all the "behind the scene" work and provides you with *.m3u8 URL. I've implemented this pattern with Wowza Streaming Engine. You can use it or similar tools.

On the flip side, if you're inclined towards having more simple and straight forward solution; more like a CDN approach, then you may follow @Bret's answer.